# Spring Boot + HikariCP - non-deterministic failure to auto-configure a DataSource

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

On my local machine, when I run one of my Spring Boot 2.0.0 applications from IntelliJ, the application periodically fails to start and the following message is displayed in the console:

> Application Failed to Start
>
> Description:
>
> Failed to auto-configure a DataSource: 'spring.datasource.url' is not specified and no embedded datasource could be auto-configured.
>
> Reason: Failed to determine a suitable drive class

When I get this error, if I try to run the application again it will (sometimes) start. The behavior seems non-deterministic. Sometimes the application starts on the first try, sometimes it takes a few consecutive attempts.

#### Edit ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

> The error appears to be caused by the application failing to determine what profile is active.  When the application fails to start, the Spring logging output states "No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default". When the application starts successfully, the logging output states "The following profiles are active: local,permitall", which are the profiles I set to active in application.properties.
>
> Unfortunately, whether or not Spring determines what profile is active when starting is a roll of the dice for me.

#### ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

My application is configured to use spring-boot-starter-data-jpa and connect to a Postgres database.  For connection pooling I use HikariCP 2.7.8.

The console error (see below) implies that Hikari is failing to load a data source.  Since this error is non-deterministic, maybe it depends on the order that Spring creates beans during startup?

The spring.datasource.url property is defined in my local application properties file. The application properties file sets the spring active profile property to local.

This is my application.properties file

```
spring.profiles.active=local,permitall 
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

This is my application-local.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/vms?currentSchema=vms
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

I haven't found a pattern to the failures or the successes. Any ideas on solving or troubleshooting this problem are appreciated.

#### Console error message

> 2018-05-18 13:53:49.667 ERROR 16228 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource
>
> [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed;
>
> nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception;
>
> nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed;
>
> nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint]: Factory method 'healthEndpoint' threw exception;
>
> nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed;
>
> nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$61a24aeb]: Constructor threw exception;
>
> nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed;
>
> nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception;
>
> nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Comment: It is non-deterministic if you use "spring.datasource.jdbc-url"

Comment: Do you mean "spring.datasource.hikari.jdbc-url"?  I tried setting this property but it did not solve the problem.  I also tried setting "spring.datasource.hikari.driver-class-name", but the problem continues.

Comment: I suggest reporting this issue in the spring-boot issue tracker.

Comment: Good suggestion. I submitted this issue to their tracker: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13256